# BearerOption.SaveToken is not saving the token in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt

I'm using .net Core Web API 3.1.2 framework and in the configurations, I have added the following code:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).
            AddJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
                **opt.SaveToken = true;**
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(_jwtSigningKey),
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });
```

Logically, opt.SaveToken = true would save the token in the server, and the Authentication method should not accept any token that was issued from any other server even if the other server is using the exact same JWT signing key since it is not saved on the server.

I made a test and uploaded the same signing key to 2 different servers and got a login token from one server, and used it to get Authenticated in the other one, and the other server accepted the token, even though it didn't have the token saved, furthermore, I accidentally added a random unique string generated value to be included in the token, so there is no way that 2 tokens can be identical.

Why is this happening?
What I'm missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by ", I accidentally added a random unique string generated value to be included in the token, so there is no way that 2 tokens can be identical." ?

Comment: @NanYu you have token 1 { k1:v1, k2:v2} if each time you will ask me to give you a token, without any variable field I will return to you the exact same data field value (except metadata like expiration date, creation date... etc that will be variable) so in order to make each token more variant than the next one that will be generated, I on purpose add a random filed that will increase uniquense of each token.

Comment: Understand , so what is your question now ? the two different tokens have different claims and they should both can access protected resource .

Comment: @NanYu My question is, by logic I understand that opt.SaveToken = true, option should save the token in the server and check if the token was created from the server, and not accept any token that was created from another server, even if the other server have the same signing key. but it is not rejecting the token, it is accepting it even though it was created from another server. the question is what's the use of opt.SaveToken = true, if it is not saving the token in the first place?

Comment: Set SaveToken = true only means you could access it through await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") for any outgoing request

Comment: @GarryXiao please write it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I double-checked the source code:
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/d1ee5a22fbda54fc2352d937d7064b451a95b72a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs

The official handbook:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.savetoken?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Set SaveToken = true only means you could access it through await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") for any outgoing request. No connections with the authentication but it's possible to implement by yourself easily.